# PHP перевод сайта

Tags: php, локализация

Есть, к примеру, 50 тысяч имён. Их нужно перевести на другой язык.

Если создам массив с переводом и буду подгружать его – это нормально при таком размере массива? Или всё же лучше создать поле в базе данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

50 тыс. имён, если, в среднем, по 8 двухбайтовых символов (т.е. 16 байт), это 800тыс байт. Ещё столько же на переводы. Итого **около 2Мб данных**, которые часто используются. Есть смысл их держать в оперативной памяти для быстрого доступа: в [Redis](http://redis.io/), [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.memcache.php) / [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.memcached.php), [apc_store](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.apc-store.php) или др. in-memory key-value storage.

**Другой вариант** – собственные средства PHP для локализации через ф-ю [`gettext()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gettext.php). Переводы строк компилируются в .po/.mo файлы, лежащие в поддиректориях на каждый язык, и в них быстро отыскиваются переводы запрошенных строк. Если сервер с SSD дисками, такой вариант, наверное, сравним по скорости с хранением в памяти.

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая что обычные php загружаются в память при каждом запросе и после выдачи страницы завершаются, то ответ однозначен, перевод хранить в БД. Загрузка в ОЗУ 50к записей ради выдачи пары из них явное расточительство.

С другой стороны, если используется технология FastCGI, при которой скрипт всегда в оперативной памяти и не завершается после выдачи очередной страницы и готов обрабатывать следующий запрос - то подход с разовой загрузкой словаря может быть правильным выбором.

Кроме того существуют специальные системы хранения, нацеленные на хранение часто используемых данных в оперативной памяти. например memcached